# How to extract the Dictionary value inside the List in the column, Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

```
 Assigne(column name)
[{'id': 2342343, 'username': 'Raj', 'color': '#08c7e0', 'profilePicture': None}]
[{'id': 764665, 'username': 'mac', 'color': '#08c7e0', 'profilePicture': None}]

name = [d.get('username') for d in df.assigne]
print (name)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing list from loop, to access dictionary use:

```
name = [d[0].get('username') for d in df.assigne]
print (name)

['Raj', 'mac']
```

**EDIT 1:** If the row contains empty list use:

```
name = [d[0].get('username') for d in df.assigne if d]
```

**EDIT 2:** If multiple dictionaries in list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[{'id':2342343, 'username':'Raj', 'color':'#08c7e0', 'profilePicture':None}]],
                   [[{'id':764665, 'username':'mac', 'color':'#08c7e0', 'profilePicture':None}]],
                   [[{'id':2342343, 'username':'Raj', 'color':'#08c7e0', 'profilePicture':None}, 
                     {'id':2342343, 'username':'mac', 'color':'#08c7e0', 'profilePicture':None}]],
                   [[]],
                   [[{'id':2342343, 'username':'sand', 'color':'#08c7e0', 'profilePicture':None}]]], 
                  columns=['Assigne'])

name = [x.get('username')  for d in df.Assigne if d for x in d]

print(name)
['Raj', 'mac', 'Raj', 'mac', 'sand']
```

Comment: what if my row values also contains empty list?

Comment: How to get all these username from  a single row value [{'id': 2342343, 'username': 'Raj', 'color': '#08c7e0', 'profilePicture': None}, {'id': 2342343, 'username': 'mac', 'color': '#08c7e0', 'profilePicture': None}, [{'id': 2342343, 'username': 'sand', 'color': '#08c7e0', 'profilePicture': None}]] ?

Comment: Thanks for your help mate.